# Are TCP setup times this slow (1 second), typically?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

My scenario is that I have a hundred small text files that I want to load, parse, and store in a DLL. Clients of the DLL are transient (command line programs), and I would prefer not to reload the data on every command line invocation.

So, I thought I would write a Windows server to store the data and have the clients query the server using TCP. But, the TCP performance was really slow. I wrote the following code using `Stopwatch` to measure the socket setup time.

```
    // time the TCP interaction to see where the time goes
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    // create and connect socket to remote host
    client = new TcpClient (hostname, hostport); // auto-connects to server
    Console.WriteLine ("Connected to {0}",hostname);

    // get a stream handle from the connected client
    netstream = client.GetStream();

    // send the command to the far end
    netstream.Write(sendbuf, 0, sendbuf.Length);
    Console.WriteLine ("Sent command to far end: '{0}'",cmd);
    stopwatch.Stop();
    sendTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Much to my surprise, that little bit of code took 1,037 milliseconds (1 second) to execute. I expected the time to be far smaller. Is that a normal socket setup time between a client and server running on a modern Windows 10 localhost?

To compare, I wrote a loop that loaded 10 files x 100 lines each, and that experiment only took 1ms. So, it was 1000x faster reading from disk (an SSD) than it was to use sockets to a server.

I know what to do in my scenario (use file reads on each invocation), but I would like to know if anyone can confirm these kinds of timings for socket setup times. Or maybe there are faster interprocess communication mechanisms for a local machine that would compare favorably with file reads/parses. I really don't want to believe that `File.ReadAllLines(filepath)` is the fastest way when spread over hundreds of command-line client invocations.

EDIT - Avoid DNS lookup by using explict IPEndPoint address

Following the comments below, I replaced "localhost" with an IPEndpoint method to set up the connection. The change reduced the 1037ms to about 20ms, but (1) the TcpClient would not automatically connect, and (2) the sending of text failed to reach the server. So, there must be something different between the original and IPEndPoint methods.

```
// new IPEndPoint method
// fast at 20ms, but the server never sees the sent text
string serverIP = "127.0.0.1";
IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse (serverIP);
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(address, hostport);
client = new TcpClient(remoteEP);
client.Connect (remoteEP);  // new; required w IPEndPoint method

// send text command to the far end
netstream = client.GetStream();
netstream.Write(sendbuf, 0, sendbuf.Length);
Console.WriteLine ("Sent command to far end: '{0}'",cmd);
stopwatch.Stop();
sendTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
Console.WriteLine ($"Milliseconds for sending by TCP:  '{sendTime}'");

// unfortunately, the server never sees the sent text now
```

I don't know why using an IPEndPoint as an input argument to TcpClient requires an explicit connect when TcpClient would automatically connect before. And I don't know why the `netstream.Write` fails now too. Examples on the net always use `socket.Connect` and `socket.Send` with IPEndPoints.

EDIT #2 - Use IPEndPoint with sockets, not streams

```
// use sockets, not streams
// This code takes 3 seconds to send text to the server
// But at least this code works. The original code was faster at 1 second.       
string serverIP = "127.0.0.1";
IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(serverIP);
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(address, hostport);
socket = new Socket (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,
                 ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Connect (remoteEP);
socket.Send (sendbuf);
```

EDIT #3 - After experiments based on Evk comments:

Using the information provided by Evk above, I did several experiments as follows. Three clients and two servers were used.

```
Client 1: DNS returns only IPv4 using new TcpClient().
Client 2: DNS returns only Ipv6 using new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InternetworkV6)
Client 3: DNS returns IPv4 and IPv6 using new TcpClient(“localhost”,port)
Server 1: IPv4 new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, port)
Server 2: IPv6 new TcpListener(IPAddress.IPv6Loopback, port)
```

From worst to best, the 6 possible pairs returned the following results:

c4xs6 - Client 1 ip4 with Server 2 ip6 – connection actively refused.

c6xs4 - Client 2 ip6 with Server 1 ip4 – connection actively refused.

c46xs4 - Client 3 (both) with Server 1 ip4, always delayed 1000ms because client tried using IPv6 before timing out and trying ip4, which worked consistently. This was the original code in this post.

C46xs6 - Client 3 (both) with Server 2 ip6, after a fresh restart of both, was fast on the first try (21ms) and on subsequent closely-spaced tries. But after waiting a minute or three, the next try was 3000ms, followed by fast 20ms times on closely-spaced subsequent tries.

C4xs4 – Same behavior as above. First try after a fresh restart was fast, as were closely-spaced subsequent tries. But after waiting a minute or two, the next try was 3000ms, followed by fast (20ms) closely-spaced subsequent tries.

C6xS6 – Same behavior as above. Fast after a fresh server reboot, but after a minute or two, a delay try (3000ms) followed by fast (20ms) responses to closely-spaced tries.

My experiments showed no consistently fast responses over time. There must be some kind of a delay or timeout or sleeping behavior when the connections go idle. I use `netstream.Close; client.Close();` to close each connection on each try. (Is that right?) I don’t know what could be causing the delayed responses after a minute or two of idle no-active-connection time.

Any idea what might be causing the delay after a minute or two of idle listening time? The client is supposedly out of the system memory, having exited the console program. The server is supposedly doing nothing new, just listening for another connection.

Comment: To exclude DNS requests, can you try your code with `client = new TcpClient(new IPEndPoint( new IPAddress(...), hostport)`

Comment: I am pretty sure this is because of slow DNS response. Try to measure a **second** connection, just after the first resolves the host name and a local cache can be used for the next connection.

Comment: Named pipes are probably the fastest way to go for local IPC only. But yea that seems like a long time to connect to a server running locally.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried the `new IPEndPoint()` mechanism to set up the connection as described above, and the time eventually dropped from 1037ms to 20ms. But, when I used the IPE method, the client did not connect automatically, and I received an error trying to `GetStream` on a "non-connected" socket. I had to call client.Connect after creating the new TcpClient object. Maybe that did something too since the server never received the outgoing Send text. I am searching for examples to follow.

Comment: When you use an IP address, IP routing and ARP is used to route to the server.  When you have DNS enabled and use HOST NAME the route is determined by requesting route from DNS server which will take longer because you first have to send message to server and get response before the message is sent.

Comment: It seems like I cannot get away from a long delay (DNS lookup?) no matter if I use `TcpClient` or `socket` or `IPEndPoint`, regardless of whether I use localhost, 127.0.0.1, or the real IP address of the machine. I would have thought that using an explicit IP address would prevent that. But there's a huge delay nonetheless.

Comment: I edited my Win10 `hosts` table to hardcode "127.0.0.1 localhost" and then used localhost and 127.0.0.1 in calls to `TcpClient` (the original code). The lowest time I could get on second, third, fourth, etc. runs of my client console program (after initial DNS resolution) was 1 second. That's still very long.

Comment: TCP is by design slow. Comparing sockets to local disk access is meaningless, as the latter is by definition faster. You already ruled out DNS but stuck on how to use `TcpClient` in a correct way. That means you should check "complete" samples. I am not sure if Microsoft has finished migrating its samples to Docs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples So you can just try your luck, or go to GitHub and search. Learn how to use System.NET tracing to analyze packets when issues happen, and that can help you a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, 1 second to establish connection to localhost is not expected perfomance. The problem in your case is not DNS lookup by itself. DNS lookup of localhost takes no time (few milliseconds maybe) and certainly cannot take 1 second. Below I assume that your TCP server is bound only to IpV4 loopback (`127.0.0.1`), for example like this:

```
var server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, port);
```

When you initialize client like this:

```
new TcpClient("localhost", port)
```

It queries DNS (which takes no time) and DNS returns 2 ip addresses: `::1` (IpV6 localhost) and `127.0.0.1` (IpV4 localhost). It has no idea whether it needs to use IpV4 or IpV6 address. So it tries both (with preference of IpV6). That 1 second delay you observe is time it needs to realize that connection to `::1` (IpV6 localhost) fails.

If you initialize client like this:

```
var client = new TcpClient();
```

It's the same as:

```
// InterNetwork means IpV4
var client = new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
```

Both those versions will bind client to local IpV4 socket. That means when you later do:

```
client.Connect("localhost", port);
```

There is no need for client to try IpV6 localhost address, because local socket is IpV4. Both this versions will remove 1 second delay you observe. Another option to remove a delay is to bind your *server* to ipv6 loopback (to `IPAddress.IPv6Loopback`).

Note that this:

```
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(address, hostport);
client = new TcpClient(remoteEP);
```

Is just wrong. This overload of `TcpClient` constructor expects *local* endpoint, not remote. In your example that should just throw exception (port already in use) on either client or server, because you are trying to bind to the same ip and port on both server and client. If you want to connect directly without DNS lookup (which takes 0 time for localhost anyway, but might be important when you connect to real server), do this:

```
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(address, hostport);
client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(remoteEP);
```

Comment: Yup, it's a ridiculous design choice by Microsoft, having such inconsistency in the `TcpClient` constructor arguments, if a string they mean the endpoint to connect to, but if pre-parsed it binds.  Terrible, terrible design.

Comment: Thank you so much for your long and informative answer. Don't worry about the localEP and remoteEP names, I was switching them to see what looked best. Interesting that you mention ipv6 vs ipv4. I read a lonely line of text in one of the webpages that ip6 would be tried first, and if that didn't work after a timeout, ip4 would be tried. In my localhost file I have both 127.0.0.1 and ::1 defined. I will go back this week and try some of your coding suggestions and report back here. Thank you so much again - it must have taken you a long time to write that! -Kevin

Comment: @Kevin problem is not names (`remoteEP`, `localEP`) but the fact that it IS really remote endpoint, so you cannot pass it to constructor of `TcpClient`. There is no ip\port you can pass in your case to that constructor, so you just should not use it. As for localhost file - it doesn't matter what is defined there. What matters is to what ip you bind _server_ (`TcpListener`). If you bind it to "::1" - your code in any form will work without delay. If you bind to "127.0.0.1" (like you do now) - some ways will give a delay and some do not (as described in answer).

Comment: @Kevin so correct ways (if your server is bound to "127.0.0.1") are either `var client = new TcpClient(); client.Connect("localhost", port);` or `var client = new TcpClient(); client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, port));` Both will give no delay (whole code you measure will complete in several milliseconds).

Comment: You correctly surmise that the server is (currently) listening using ip4. I wondered about trying to use ip6 when I read that one tiny sentence (among thousands) in the docs. But I didn't have time to experiment because I couldn't find an example using ip6. I will get to it this week. Thank you for the explicit statement of what will work (or not) in the previous comment. Where in the world did you learn so much about this since there is precious little I could find on the net. I want to learn about it too... :-)

Comment: @Kevin I also happened to face this issue some time ago. To figure it all out I had to explore TcpClient source code at that time. So, from experience :)

Comment: Well, your experience certainly shows, and I am grateful to you for sharing it. (I didn't even know that source code was available!) I will report back after some testing.

Comment: See EDIT 3 above in the original post. There I report the interesting results from my experiments based on Evk's answer/information. There's still a surprising delay in the connections sometimes after only a minute of idle no-active-connections.

Comment: @Kevin I see but that 's a different story :) Initial question was about slow "startup" times. Maybe worth asking separate question (because the reason is likely to be diffeent).

Comment: Ok, I will do that. Thanks.

Comment: Follow up question found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387687/tcp-first-connection-setup-times-increase-to-1-3-sec-after-a-1-minute-idle-inter