# TCP first connection setup times increase to 1-3 sec after a 1-minute idle interval

Tags: c#, tcp, timeout, windows-10

My original scenario ([see the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49341481/are-tcp-setup-times-this-slow-1-second-typically)) was that I have a hundred small text files that I want to load, parse, and store in a DLL. Clients of the DLL are transient (command line programs), and I would prefer not to reload the data on every command line invocation. (But this post is about the matrix of TCP client/server IPv4/IPv6 connections from my experiments described below.)

So, I thought I would write a Windows server to store the data and have the clients query the server using TCP. But, the TCP performance was really slow. I wrote the following code using `Stopwatch` to measure the socket setup time.

```
    // time the TCP interaction to see where the time goes
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    // create and connect socket to remote host
    client = new TcpClient (hostname, hostport); // auto-connects to server
    Console.WriteLine ("Connected to {0}",hostname);

    // get a stream handle from the connected client
    netstream = client.GetStream();

    // send the command to the far end
    netstream.Write(sendbuf, 0, sendbuf.Length);
    Console.WriteLine ("Sent command to far end: '{0}'",cmd);
    stopwatch.Stop();
    sendTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Much to my surprise, that little bit of code took 1,037 milliseconds (1 second) to execute. I expected the time to be far smaller. The reason for the 1-second setup time was that the syntax of the `new TcpClient(hostname, port)` code caused DNS to return both IPv6 and IPv4 addresses. During connection, the client tried IPv6 to the server first and had to wait for a timeout before falling back to IPv4 (which the server was using).

After a great [answer from @Evk about TcpClient syntax and IPv6 / IPv4 here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49341481/are-tcp-setup-times-this-slow-1-second-typically), I did several experiments as follows. Three clients and two servers were used to test the various syntaxes and behaviors:

```
Client 1: DNS returns only IPv4 using new TcpClient().
Client 2: DNS returns only Ipv6 using new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InternetworkV6)
Client 3: DNS returns IPv4 and IPv6 using new TcpClient(“localhost”,port)
Server 1: IPv4 new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, port)
Server 2: IPv6 new TcpListener(IPAddress.IPv6Loopback, port)
```

From worst to best, the 6 possible pairs returned the following results:

c4xs6 - Client 1 ip4 with Server 2 ip6 – connection actively refused.

c6xs4 - Client 2 ip6 with Server 1 ip4 – connection actively refused.

c46xs4 - Client 3 (uses both v6 and v4) with Server 1 ip4, always delayed 1000ms because client tried using IPv6 before timing out and trying ip4, which worked consistently. This was the original code in this post.

C46xs6 - Client 3 (uses both v6 and v4) with Server 2 ip6, after a fresh restart of both, was fast on the first try (21ms) and on subsequent closely-spaced tries. But after waiting a minute or three, the next try was 3000ms, followed by fast 20ms times on closely-spaced subsequent tries.

C4xs4 – Same behavior as above. First try after a fresh restart was fast, as were closely-spaced subsequent tries. But after waiting a minute or two, the next try was 3000ms, followed by fast (20ms) closely-spaced subsequent tries.

C6xS6 – Same behavior as above. Fast after a fresh server reboot, but after a minute or two, a delayed try (3000ms) was observed followed by fast (20ms) responses to closely-spaced tries.

My experiments showed no consistently fast responses over time. There must be some kind of a delay or timeout or sleeping behavior when the connections go idle. I use `netstream.Close; client.Close();` to close each connection on each try. (Is that right?) I don’t know what could be causing the delayed responses after a minute or two of idle no-active-connection time.

Any idea what might be causing the delay after a minute or two of idle listening time? The client is supposedly out of the system memory, having exited the console program. The server is supposedly doing nothing new, just listening for another connection.

Restarting the server gives fast initial (and closely-spaced (10-sec apart) responses, but the first connection after a 1 or 2-minute delay gives a slow response. When things go idle for a while, it's like the server decides something and starts to make the client wait for a bit before responding. I suggest that the server is at fault because (1) the client isn't even running during the idle time, and so it cannot decide anything; and (2) restarting the server gives a fast response.

Keep-alive pings don't seem appropriate because the client is not trying to keep the connection open-it closes both the netstream and the client after each short call, as shown above.

Does anyone have an idea of what is happening, and what (if anything) I can do about it?

EDIT #1 - the almost-complete source code, as requested below

Client code:

```
try {
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    client = new TcpClient(); // DNS forces use of v4
    client.Connect("localhost", hostport);
    netstream = client.GetStream();
    netstream.Write(sendbuf, 0, sendbuf.Length);

    stopwatch.Stop();
    sendTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    Console.WriteLine($"Milliseconds for sending by TCP:  '{sendTime}'");
     // receive the bytes back from the far end
    ...
catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine (ex.Message);
}
finally {
    client?.Close(); // close the client after receiving server response
}
```

Server code:

```
listener = null;

// try to start a listener
listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, hostport); // uses v4
Console.WriteLine("Listening on v4 only...");
listener.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Listener is listening on port {0}", hostport);
rxbuf = new byte[BUFSIZE];              // the buffer
inbytes = 0;                            // nbytes rx
// loop forever handling clients one at a time
for (; ; ) {
    client = null;
    netstream = null;

    try {
        client = listener.AcceptTcpClient(); // get client connection
        netstream = client.GetStream(); // get the receiving stream

        Console.WriteLine("Accepted a client...Reading...");
        totalbytes = 0;

        inbytes = netstream.Read(rxbuf, // the buf
        totalbytes,                     // write new bytes here
        rxbuf.Length - totalbytes);     // read this many bytes
        if (inbytes == 0)               // if no bytes read
            break;                      // break loop

        totalbytes = totalbytes + inbytes; // update total bytes read
        inbytes = 0;
         // - show what you received from the client
        backcmd = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rxbuf, 0, totalbytes);
        Console.WriteLine("Rx command: '{0}'", backcmd);
        Console.WriteLine("Running command: '{0}'", backcmd);
         // - get a new process info structure to run the external command
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        ... run the 40-char cmd from the client
        ... collect the output from the console app run on the server side
        string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        ...
        byte[] tosend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(output);
        netstream.Write (tosend, 0, output.Length);

        // client runs 'client.Close()' after receiving this text
        // so the server should close this connection automatically too.
        // Adding a 'client.Close();' statement here made no difference.
    }
    // - catch and write exceptions to console, closing stream
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        netstream?.Close();
    }
}                                       // for ever
// I wonder if I should (could) close something here if the
// code breaks out of the loop, but everything works fine so
// I have no code here.

 return 0;
```

Comment: Are you making a new connection for every file? Have you considered sending them all at once? You could send the number of files followed by each file prefixed with a length.

Comment: I am not sending files at all, just a 40-character command to the server, collecting its response and then shutting down the connection. I hit the up-arrow on my keyboard to reload the client command and then hit Enter; repeating that 10 times gives fast 20ms responses. No, I don't think I'm running out of ports, since the server always uses the same port (as does the client). I reuse the same ports on localhost because I close the test connection as soon as I get a response from the server. Using DNS and direct IPs makes no difference.

Comment: "just a 40-character command to the server, collecting its response and then shutting down the connection" - At what frequency? Is the behavior the same if you omit DNS and directly use IPs? Local ports don't return to "available" at once. They need a little recover time. So it is possible to run into a wall there, although I don't think this is your issue here.

Comment: Instead of host name use IP address and see if it is faster.  Usually host name has to be verified by DNS Server which slow down the time.  IP address using IP routing which does not need the server.

Comment: And: Have you tried measuring without Console-IO contamination?

Comment: Agreed, that's not the problem because the problem shows up _after_ a 1-minute delay, and then only for the first connection (3000ms). Subsequent connections are fast (20ms) again. I have always used tiny console apps for testing since that is the use case for the project. I have never heard of Console-IO contamination in 40 years.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I asked for frequency but it's clear from the question already. My remaining suspects are DNS or contaminated measurement.

Comment: "I have never heard of Console-IO contamination in 40 years"  then it's about time ... I had once a logger disrupting performance measurements and it took ages to convince the executing dev to exclude that IO from measurement of the operation in question. Turned out he was chasing a problem that wasn't there.

Comment: It was hard to believe that the Stopwatch class would work fine with closely-spaced calls a few seconds apart but would contaminate the console client when it wasn't even running. Nonetheless, I removed the Stopwatch code and ran the experiments over again. The behavior was the same. The first connection after a 1-minute delay took a relatively long time (can't say exactly how long because the Stopwatch was unavailable).

Comment: @Kevin, This is interesting. I'm curious if the closures are going well. As a side note, per MSDN, you only need to call `Close()` on the client and everything else will get closed.

Comment: I wonder if you could view the packets with Wireshark.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't what I meant. I meant just put Console Output before Stopwatch.Start or after stopwatch.stop ... so you are only measuring the actual creation, get stream and send operations.

Comment: Can you post full code of both client and server? Even if  you think code is trivial.

Comment: Code posted as requested. I want to bet that the server is not quite right, since restarting the server after the 1-2 minute interval always produces a fast first connection. But I don't know enough to see what is wrong.

Comment: Did you ensure that delay is not server's fault (by using Stopwatch on server to measure processing time after command is received)? For example maybe that process.waitforexit takes all that time for some reason.

Comment: Stopwatch on the server shows a consistent ~125ms time between accepting the client and sending back the response. About ~124ms of the time (ie, all of it) is consumed by the Process.Start code that runs a small console program on the server side. Thus about zero time is spent waiting for the process to exit. Besides, the issue is with the first connection after 1-minute of silence from the client (with no attempts to connect to the server). What can the server be thinking after the timeout (assuming an inactivity timeout.) It feels like the old ipv6/ipv4 issue, but both are locked to ipv4.

Comment: Just a theory. What if after 1 minute of no use, server says "This port can't be used again reinitialized?" Then when it sees the first incoming client connection after 1 minute, it reinitializes the port and starts taking connections again for closely-spaced conversations. When no clients connect for a minute, the server marks the port as requiring reinitialization until the next client calls. Does that match the server code? I read that servers keep status at the time of last successful packet sent (conn is up and active), even though the conn has been closed by client long ago.